# Can we use "not" after verbs?

Tags: grammar

Can we say "I come not" or use "not" after verbs  like that sentence in English ?

Comment: 'I come not to bury Caesar' is a well known variant on a line from Shakespeare. 'I come not to bury Caesar, but to name a salad after him' is perhaps less well known. But except when using certain uncommon styles, saying 'I come not ...' will make you sound like a rank amateur.

Comment: Ask not what a verb can do for you, ask what you can do for your verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. I don't think that's a duplicate: it does cover the now rare rhetorical use of *not* with finite verbs, but never really addresses OP's underlying question about the use of *not* with verbs generally.

Comment: @StoneyB OP's 'Can we say "I come not" or use "not" after verbs like that sentence in English?' would seem to restrict the scope to main verbs and modern English.

Answer (score 2):

Usage is different in finite and non-finite clauses—that is, in clauses which use 'tensed' verbs, imperatives and subjunctives, and clauses which use participles and infinitives.

In pre-Modern English finite clauses any verb could be negated directly:

> I pray thee, stay with us. **Go not** to Wittenberg. —*Hamlet*
>   Love **looks not** with the eyes but with the mind. —*MND*

This use survives in proverbial fixed phrases like *waste not, want not* and archaicizing rhetorical flourishes. Otherwise, Modern English finite negations attach *not* only to auxiliary verbs; if there is no auxiliary in the affirmative version, *do* is recruited as a dummy auxiliary:

> **Do not go** ...
>   Love **does not look** ...

In non-finite clauses *not* is still permitted with lexical verbs, but is usually set before the verb, not after it:

> Hamlet considered **not staying** in Denmark.
>   **Not deterred** by John's objections, Amy continued.
>   **Not to contradict** you, but that seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by modern English.  Perhaps you are instead thinking of least-common-denominator, semi-literate English?  One can certainly find examples of modern usage.  Kennedy's famous "Ask not what your country..." speech comes to mind.

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks for the catch. I had edited in a phrase --"rhetorical flourishes"--to cover things like that, but it somehow ended up in a repost as a separate answer. I've now deleted that one, and restored the phrase  to its proper place here.

Comment: This is a good answer largely, though I think in Early Modern English (up to late 17th century), direct negation was acceptable for all verbs. I still think think it's *acceptable* for all verbs even nowadays, it's just archaic. But that's my view.

Comment: @Noldorin I agree; I was counting EME as Pre-Modern.

Comment: Okay, then all is good!

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it could sound very formal or pompous.

Routinely I'd say 'I don't come ...'

Of course it is acceptable after modal verbs; I can not, I do not, I might not etc.

Comment: It's not Modern English. It's [Early Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English), which includes Shakespeare and the King James Bible. The syntax rules were different, and so were the word usages. Talking this way is hard to do right (is it _dost thou_ or _doth thou_?), because it's a different language and you don't know all the rules. It's really just embarrassing, not formal.